# Closing a browser tab opened using Desktop Browser in Java

Tags: java, runtime, desktop

I am using Desktop.browse in a java program to open a new browser tab, the new tab opening triggers a file download from the specified url, after the file download, the tab opened by my program must be closed/destroyed.

The open event works fine and the new browser tab opens and the file downloads, after that am unable to figure out how to close the existing tab.

I have tried the following options so far:

Option 1:

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(new URI("http://google.pl"));
d.wait(1000);
d.destroy();  //error -> there is no destroy option in Desktop. This is ideally what we need to do.
```

Option 2:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
//this opens a new browser tab and loads the url we need
Process process = runtime.exec("open " + url); 

Thread.sleep(1000);
process.destroy(); // this does not close the tab
```

Any pointers on how closing the browser tab can be achieved will be very helpful. Searched on SO but could not find a solution that works.

Comment: Why even open a tab to download something?  It would probably be better to directly download from the URL in Java.

Comment: Its a secure url and requires a signed in session on the browser to the portal to trigger the download via a new tab.

Comment: Yup. What you want, is impossible (Well, would take weeks of development and java would be highly unsuitable for the job, you'd have to make all sorts of windows API calls). Browsers intentionally don't exactly make it easy for you to start closing random tabs.